# Javascript images error in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, image

After moving to Wordpress the images of weather cannot be retrieved even though the JavaScript code runs fine. Here is the code that I am using to retrieve images in custom.js. The code:

```
$('#weather').openWeather({
    city: 'New York, US',
    placeTarget: '.weather-place',
    iconTarget: '.weather-icon',
    customIcons: 'files/img/icons/weather/'
});
```

There is something wrong with

```
'files/img/icons/weather/'
```

Well firstly when using html the javascript was in `files/js/custom.js` and the images were in `files/img/weather/` it worked but now with wordpress it does'nt work

Your help would be appreciated.

The files folder is in the root directory.

Comment: Could you please provide detailed information?
your question is unclear.

Comment: please describe in detail. it would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the edited answer

Comment: That's some nice-looking JavaScript, but it doesn't tell us anything about your environment or what's different than the previous.

Comment: Alright wait. Let me get you more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `files` directory branches off the `root`, then try adding a slash before the word "files", like so: `customIcons: '/files/img/icons/weather/'`

Else, you may need to provide the entire path `http://www.mydomain.com/files/...`

**ALSO**, you're not providing a file name `/files/img/icons/weather/icon.jpg`

Comment: Well the icon.jpg is not necessary because i am using the directory only.  /files/img/icons/weather/ does not work

Comment: Be sure to look where your directories are. Depending how you set this up, your `/files` directory could be within WP's directory structure, something like `/wp-content/files/img/etc...`.

Comment: Please provide the HTML and methods that are calling the script.

Comment: Well firstly when using html the javascript was in files/js/custom.js and the images were in files/img/weather/ it worked like a charm but now with wordpress it doesn't. I'll give more detail if needed

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. FYI, you may be able to get away with using only the portion of the path after the domain. Just be sure to include a starting slash `/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you moved to wordpress, the paths might have changed. Where do you keep your javscript library?

I would use the debug console from your browser to see what happens and which icons your script is trying to get and then modify the path. (press F12 and click on the "network" tab, reload the page and check for 404 errors)

Comment: Well firstly when using html the javascript was in files/js/custom.js and the images were in files/img/weather/  it worked like a charm but now with wordpress it doesn't